# Need Help Setting up TinyDNS

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, tinydns

I recently successfully installed TinyDNS on my CentOS server. I have followed these examples and guides [here,](http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2010/12/setting-up-tinydns-on-amazons-linux/) [here,](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linuxquestions-org-member-success-stories-23/tinydns-here-is-an-example-135194/) and [here.](http://rscott.org/dns/soa.html)

The issue is that I am unable to nslookup/ping any domains I setup in the data file for TinyDNS. I have 2 name servers registered through my domain registrar to ns1.minecraft-cheats.com and ns2.minecraft-cheats.com with 2 IP addresses pointing to the same server (the server with the TinyDNS on it). Here is the layout of my /var/dnscache/tinydns/root/data file:

```
Zminecraft-cheats.com:ns1.minecraft-cheats.com:2011070501:4800:1800:604800
&minecraft-cheats.com:184.168.110.107:ns1.minecraft-cheats.com:3600
&minecraft-cheats.com:184.168.123.220:ns2.minecraft-cheats.com:3600
=minecraft-cheats.com:178.63.65.196
=www.minecraft-cheats.com:178.63.65.196
```

When I use dig on the domain here is the results:

```
[root@ip-184-168-110-107 root]# dig minecraft-cheats.com

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-4.P1.el5_5.3 <<>> minecraft-cheats.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62345
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;minecraft-cheats.com.          IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
minecraft-cheats.com.   86400   IN      A       178.63.65.196

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
minecraft-cheats.com.   3600    IN      NS      ns1.minecraft-cheats.com.
minecraft-cheats.com.   3600    IN      NS      ns2.minecraft-cheats.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.minecraft-cheats.com. 3600  IN      A       184.168.110.107
ns2.minecraft-cheats.com. 3600  IN      A       184.168.123.220

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul  5 10:52:26 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 122
```

I am aware it isn't very safe to post the real IP and domain name but I really don't care right now.

When I edit the data file I am running 'make' and then restarting the TinyDNS service.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Yes, I have waited hours for propagation to occur so I do not think that is the issue at the moment.

Found a good website that diagnoses DNS issues: http://www.intodns.com/minecraft-cheats.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions by the pseudonymous `cyberx86` that you have followed are wrong.  As written, you'll end up with two different severs, one `dnscache` and `tinydns`, providing two different services but both listening on the same IP address and port.  This explains the currently observable behaviour, that all of your servers appear to be `dnscache` not `tinydns`.  Xe has made a further error of having `/etc/resolv.conf` pointing to the wrong type of DNS server, as well.

Follow [the instructions from the author of the program](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/run-server.html), instead.

Comment: Extremely helpful, I have it working now but only on 1 IP address (I have 3 I want to use). Not sure how to go about doing that

Comment: Three service instances, one per IP address, all sharing a single `root` directory with symbolic links.  Simple.  

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to update the nameservers for the domain. In your data file you list `ns1/ns2.minecraft-cheats.com` but the whois info shows `dns1/dns2.namecheaphosting.com`.

Comment: Okay I just changed that, I'll give it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run `dig @8.8.8.8 minecraft-cheats.com NS` and get a nameserver spit back at you. I can't; therefore, your problem is with your registrar. Talk to them. Your TinyDNS setup seems fine.

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/hbqrzhq054zfbeax6nvlua Is what I get

Comment: Looks to me like the query failed. You should update your registrar's NS records. You'll need to both create the glue records and set your domain to use them; I'm guessing you only did the former.

Comment: I think I know what you are talking about, I just changed those settings (d'oh) and I will see what happens in a little bit.